# Gradle error after updating Android Studio to 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

Today I have updated my Android Studio to v1.5. I have libgdx project that works well until this update. Now I get this error message.

```
    Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.mvn3.org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

[image: error message]

I've try deleting .gradle folder, restarting Android Studio, cleaning project , but I get the same error.

Thanks for help

Comment: What OS are you on? I use Ubuntu and I had issues when I upgraded to Android Studio 1.5.

Comment: @Little Child Windows 8.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just need to update gradle build tool in main gradle file

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-04'
```

to:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.9.0'
```

Comment: what file are you referring too? I see no classpaths in any gradle file

Comment: I my case I updated classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.9.0' to 1.9 (gradle is 2.0) and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be incompatible with Gradle and maven version
delete project dir/gradle/wrapper 
put a right version gradle into it 
run again

https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin