# How to fix Android Studios error: "unable to load class 'org.gradle.mvn3

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

[Unable to load class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN2Gx.jpg)

I'm started developing still learning a course from udacity on 2D development  (Libgdx). And I donwloadEd their files and can't run them, as there is a gradle sync error.

In the message tab it says:

> Unable to load class 'org.gradle.mvn3.org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtificialResolutionExpception'

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ScareCrew please add your build.gradle file of your root project

Comment: Well I downloadEd a project from the internet and trying to load it  (its quiet old)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle error after updating Android Studio to 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120392/gradle-error-after-updating-android-studio-to-1-5)

Answer (score 2):

I kindly recommended to use the below classpath in your build.gradle file.

```
  classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.9.0'
```

or Downgrade the classpath

Comment: Excuse me but I'm still quiet new with android studios. Where is the build.gradle file found?

Comment: It will be present inside the root directory (inside your project directory)